# Powershell profile Set-Location cannot find Path? But works normally otherwise

Tags: windows, powershell, path, onedrive

`Set-location 'C:\Users\me\OneDrive - Freie Universität Berlin'`

Including the above in the PowerShell profile leads to "path cannot be found because it doesn't exist" error. It does exist, and a running PowerShell executes the exact same command without issue.

I've tried double quotes, I've tried `-LiteralPath`.
Using `Set-location 'C:\Users\me\temp'` in the profile works.

Edit: It's the "ä" character. An identical folder name (without "ä") has no problems. Unfortunately OneDrive folders like this one can't be renamed easily. The same command works just fine if copied into PS

Comment: does the profile work if you start without one ... and then call it manually?

Comment: That gives exactly the same results. It must be that "ä" character or the spaces. Unfortunately you can't rename OneDrive folders either. Edit: It works with an identical folder name that doesn't have "ä"

Comment: ah! double check the encoding for your profile file ... the default encoding does NOT handle non-ascii text gracefully.  [*sigh ...*]

Comment: Thanks! That was it.

Comment: kool! glad to help - and that you got it working as needed ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed encoding of the profile.ps1 to "UTF-8-BOM" in Notepad++, now PS handles non-ASCII correctly